# Why do the first two of four principal compenents produce less differentiated clusters than a scatterplot of two original variables?

Tags: clustering, pca

I've been experimenting with the Palmer Penguins dataset (https://allisonhorst.github.io/palmerpenguins/) to understand principal components analysis. To get a sense of the structure of the data in advance, I looked at scatterplot matrix of the continuous variables colored by `species` and found that a scatterplot of `bill_depth_mm` vs. `bill_length_mm` separates the `species` quite well:

```r
library(palmerpenguins)
library(ggplot2)
penguins_complete <- penguins[complete.cases(penguins),]
ggplot(penguins_complete, aes(bill_length_mm, bill_depth_mm, color = species)) + geom_point() + 
    stat_ellipse(geom="polygon", alpha = .2, aes(fill = species))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Next I found the first two principal components using the four continuous variables in the dataset, adding `flipper_length_mm` and `body_mass_g` to the two variables in the scatterplot above. I then created a biplot following the method described in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKl4LJAXnEA. I expected the biplot to improve the clustering further given that we now have information about four variables, rather than just two, in the two principal components. To my surprise, the `species` clusters turned out to be less differentiated in this biplot than in the scatterplot above:

```r
library(palmerpenguins)
library(ggplot2)
penguins_complete <- penguins[complete.cases(penguins),]
pca <- prcomp(penguins_complete[,3:6], scale. = TRUE)
ggplot(cbind(penguins_complete, pca$x), aes(PC1, PC2, color = species, fill = species)) +
        stat_ellipse(geom="polygon", alpha = .2) + geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

What's going on?

Comment: But it is pretty good in differentiating the Gentoo from these other two, isn't it? Which make me think how to exactly quantify and conclude something to be "less differentiated". Btw, as your PCA captures the variability in the dataset of 4 variables, I think it fairer to compare its performance with 4C2 = 6 plots of 2 variables.

Comment: @panda I hear what you're saying and I definitely cherry-picked the best scatterplot, but still, generally models don't get worse if you add variables.

Comment: PCs are not derived with the goal of optimizing separation. Try canonical discriminant functions instead.